# Handling concurrency access for deleting an object using Ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, concurrency

i have the following view inside my asp.net MVC application that contains an ajax.actionlink for deleting objects:-

```
<table id="incrementanswer">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Answer 
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers.OrderBy(a => a.IsRight))
{
       <tr id =  @answer.AnswersID>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Answer_Description.description)
        </td>
        <td>

       @{ string i = "Are uou sure you want to delete " + @answer.Description.ToString() + " ?";}
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = i,
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              OnBegin = string.Format(
                       "disablelink({0})",
                       Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID)),
              OnSuccess = string.Format(
                        "deleteconfirmation3({0},{1})",
                        Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID), Json.Encode(answer.Description))
          })  </td>
        </tr>}</table>
```

and the following post delete action method that will be called by the above ajax link:-

```
[HttpPost] 
        public void Delete(int id) 
        {       var a = repository.FindAnswer(id); 
                repository.DeleteAnswer(a); 
                repository.Save();}
```

and the folloiwng OnSuccess script:-

```
function deleteconfirmation3(rid, rname) {
    $('#' + rid).remove();
    jAlert(rname + ' Was Deleted Succsfully succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');}
```

currently if two user access the same view and then they both click on the delete link which is associated with the same object, then a null exception will be raised on one of the requests; so how i can handle this issue both on the action method side and on the view side to display a friendly message to the user; in these two cases:-

1. either when the  `var a = repository.FindAnswer(id);` returns a null
   exception?
2. Or when the   `repository.Save();` does not delete any record?

BR

**Edit:-**

i updated the post action method to the following:-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {

        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            var a = repository.FindAnswer(id);

            repository.DeleteAnswer(a);
            repository.Save();
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = "True", id = id, description = a.Description }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException) {
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = "False" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  }}
```

and on the view i update ajax.actionlink to the folloiwng:-

```
@{ string i = "Are uou sure you want to delete " + @answer.Description.ToString() + " ?";}
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              //OnBegin = "deleteconfirmation1",
              Confirm = i,
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              OnBegin = string.Format(
                       "disablelink({0})",
                       Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID)),

              OnSuccess =  "myresponse" 
        })
```

and the Onsuccess script:-

```
    function myresponse(data) {
    if (data.IsSuccess == "True") 
    {
        $('#' + data.id ).remove();
        jAlert(data.description + ' Was Deleted Succsfully succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
    }
    else {
        $('#' + data.id).remove();
        jAlert(data.description + 'record has already been deleted', 'aaaa');
    } 
}
```

**The above code worked fine when i test it ,, but does this approach sound acceptable as i have not written something similar to this before?**
BR

Comment: I don't think this is a point to develop some transactions to allow open one data item just by one browser window. What is the goal in this question? Concurrency problems always connects with update action not delete. If user will try to delete already removed item just show him message, it wouldn't harm your business logic.

Comment: in my application more than one user will have the permission to delete the same object. so returning a message to a user that the object  Was Deleted Succsfully, even if that object was already deleted by another user might cause some inconsistency problems ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check such that if the record exists delete it or else show a message specifying that the record has already been deleted...

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Delete(int id) 
{       var a = repository.FindAnswer(id); 
        if(/*check if a is not null*/){
        repository.DeleteAnswer(a); 
        repository.Save();
        return Json(new{ IsSuccess="True", id=id,description=a.Description });
        }else{
            // display a message record already been deleted
          return Json(new{ IsSuccess="False" });
       }     

 }
```

apparantly you will need to change the return type from void to `ActionResult` or `JsonResult`

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              Confirm = i,
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              OnBegin = string.Format(
                       "disablelink({0})",
                       Json.Encode(answer.AnswersID)),
              OnSuccess = "myResponse"
          })
```

the success handler will be like

```
function myResponse(data){
 if(data.IsSuccess=="True")
   jAlert(data.description + ' Was Deleted Succsfully succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
  else {
   alert("record has already been deleted");
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if i do the above check "if(/*check if a is not null*/)" on the Post action method as mentioned on your post, then two users might get the same result that “a” is not null if they click on the "delete" exactly at the same time so the problem will still occur??? Do I understand the code logic wrong?

Comment: SEE MY UPDATE. Instead of performing the check on the post action uisng "if(/*check if a is not null*/)""  , i am returning different Json data; one on the Try and other on the Catch (ArgumentNullException). so is this apprach acceptable??..

Comment: no matter ho fast both the user click on the same delete link at the same time one request will arrive at the server first so the second (not so fastest) request will get the record already deleted

Comment: the approach you are try to implement is also fine, can't say much about it, if it works for you then go for it

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but if two delete requests arrive at the same time , they will be processed in parallel so they will receive the same results for the following two checks:- 1. var a = repository.FindAnswer(id) 2. if(/*check if a is not null*/).  so this means that checking the existence of the record before deleting it on the post action method might not work all the time on large websites ? is my point valid?

Comment: i guess that pretty much say waht i mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/a/9725306/1193055